# MongoDB with Ninject: Resolving Dependencies From Repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, ninject, onion-architecture

OK so i think i have a fundamental gap on how Ninject works across assemblies that i'm hoping someone can help me on.

I have a asp.net mvc website that references a Core.dll which contains my domain objects and my repository and some services. My domain object has a constructor and a method that looks like this

```
public class MyMessage{
   private IMyService _myService;
   public MyMessage(IMyService myService) {...}
   public void Send() { //uses IMyService }
}
```

My repository just returns an `IEnumerable<MyMessage>`.

In my asp.net mcv website controller I am injecting the repository and calling 
`var msg = await myRepository.GetOneAsync(id)`. I then want to call `msg.send()`.

The problem i'm facing is that `_myService` is always null when the object returns from the repository.

*UPDATED TO ADD INFO ON REPOSITORY*

The code for myRepositry.Get looks like this:

```
public async Task<MyMessage> GetOneAsync(string messageId) 
=> await Collection.Find(q => q.Id == messageId).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Where Collection is a `IMongoCollection<MyMesage>`. So essentially the Mongo 2.0 C# driver is serializing the object for me and I can't seem to make Ninject resolve the dependencies when it does.

If i call `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyMessage>()`it works correctly but never when the object is created via the repository.

Is what's i'm trying to achieve possible? If so, how? If not, what are my options? Currently i'm just creating dependency resolved MyMessage and hydrating it based on what the repository returns.

Thanks,

Comment: How is your repository implemented?

Comment: Your question is sort of all over the place, and doesn't really provide any real information to make a recommendation.  What exactly do you mean by "When the object is created by the repository"?  How does your repository create MyMessages?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch updated to add some information on the repository. Does that help?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that you are relying on MongoDB to create your MyMessages, which of course doesn't work because MongoDB doesn't know anything about Ninject.  Your DI container has to create the objects in order for that to work, not Mongo.  I don't know anything about Mongo, but you might want to look for some kind of extension point that controls how objects are created, and use Ninject for that somehow.  This is more a mongodb issue than a Ninject one.

Answer (score -3):

You need to change myService to _myService as below:

```
public MyMessage(IMyService _myService) {...}
```

Since ninject requires same object name to inject instance.

Comment: Ninject does not have this requirement AFAIK

Comment: Same object name as far as the interface registered with the container, but yes we don't match up the  names and it works fine.